# Implementing binary search tree, "return from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm currently learning C and I'm having a problem implementing binary search trees.

I have declared the node and tree structures, but the compiler gives me the "incompatible pointer type" warning for the following four functions which returns or modifies the left and right pointers for each node.

I tried reading the other similar questions already but I can't understand why, as all types should be `node *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
} node;

typedef struct{
    node *root;
    int size;
} tree;

node* getLeft(node *n){
    return n->left;
}

node* getRight(node *n){
    return n->right;
}

void setLeft(node *n, node *i){
    n->left=i;
}

void setRight(node *n, node *d){
    n->right=d;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The error messages were:

```
ask.c: In function ‘getLeft’:
ask.c:16:5: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
     return n->left;
     ^
ask.c: In function ‘getRight’:
ask.c:20:5: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
     return n->right;
     ^
ask.c: In function ‘setLeft’:
ask.c:24:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
     n->left=i;
            ^
ask.c: In function ‘setRight’:
ask.c:28:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
     n->right=d;
             ^
```

Comment: Drop the useless `typedef`s and consistently use `struct node`/`struct tree` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The node `typedef` declaration is not correct. It refer to `struct node` which does not exist. The fix is simply to use a named struct rather than an anonymous struct (probably what you intended to do anyway).

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
} node;
```

Comment: Wow, that fixed it! Thank you. Is declaring anonymous strucs a bad practice then, or are there certain conditions I should be aware of like this?

Comment: @leftright1 Anonymous structs are syntactically fine but cannot be used when the struct is self referencing (as it is in this case). But be aware that some people would argue that typedefing structs at all is bad practice as it hides the true nature of the type.

Comment: @leftright1 And now you are using two "different" types, which actually are the same; this does not stand for consistent coding style.